# throw new TypeError('Invalid schema configuration: ' +

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am writing to you about the following, I am presenting an error when being able to make a reference between schemas,

I tell you a bit what I want to do, I need to create a group where I can insert the contacts or the array of contacts where I get the reference from the controller, Now ... my Schemas are as follows and it gives me the following error

```
        throw new TypeError('Invalid schema configuration: ' +
        ^

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `email`.See for a list of valid schema types.
```

Modelo User

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ContactSchema = new Schema({
      user :{ type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
      email: { type:String, trim:true}
      },{   versionKey:false,
            timestamps:true,      
});

var Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);

var UserSchema = new Schema({
      name: { type:String,  trim:true, require:true},
      lastname: { type:String,  trim:true,  require:true},
      email:[ { type:String, unique:true, trim:true, require:true}],
      password: { type:String, trim:true, required: [true,'El Password debe ser mas de 6 caracteres']},
      nPhone: { type:String, trim:true, required: [true,'El Numero debe insertar el umero de telefono']},
      photoProfile:{ type:String, default:'Image.png'},
      contacts:[ContactSchema] 
      },{   versionKey:false,
            timestamps:true,      
});


//metodo para Eliminar password
UserSchema.methods.toJSON=function () {
      var obj =this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      
      return obj;
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Models USER

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');
const  ContactSchema = require('../models/user');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MessageSchema =  new Schema({

    messageContent:{ type:String },
    //idStatusMessage:{ type:Boolean },
    user :{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
    urlFile:{ type:String, default:'Image.png'},
},{     versionKey:false,
        timestamps:true, 

});

var Message = mongoose.model('Message' ,MessageSchema);

var GroupsSchema =  new Schema({
    nameChat:{ type:String },
    user :{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'}, 
    //email: [{ type:String, unique:true, trim:true, require:true}],
    email:[ContactSchema] , 
    messageContent:{ type:String },
    messages:[MessageSchema] 
},{     versionKey:false,
        timestamps:true,      
});

//cargar grupos
GroupsSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

module.exports  = mongoose.model('Group',  GroupsSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change ContactSchema to this

```
var ContactSchema = new Schema({
      user :{ type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
      email: { type:String, trim:true}
      },{   versionKey:false,
            timestamps:true,      
});
```

And where are you importing it do it like make sure to place .schema at the end.

```
var UserSchema = require('../Models/User').schema;
```

Comment: Hello friend, what I would like is to be able to save the contact's reference by passing the email from the contact schema to the group schema, for example ... a user X, I create a Group Z and the contacts in the group were obtained from the Schema user X's contacts and I am importing it to the Groups controller. I need the reference to be contacts: email: [Contact]